# How to iterate only the first 3 elements of an array and access the keys/values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, slice

I was trying to assign each seller their monthly points, based on the amount of products they sell. The numbers, however, are just an example.
This is my code so far:

```
$sellers = array(
    'Edvin'   => 10, 
    'Julio'   =>  9, 
    'Rene'    =>  8, 
    'Jorge'   =>  7, 
    'Marvin'  =>  6,
    'Brayan'  =>  5, 
    'Sergio'  =>  4,   
    'Delfido' =>  3, 
    'Jhon'    =>  2
);

$a = 1;
foreach ($sellers as $seller => $points) {
    while ($a < 4) {
        echo "The seller top " . $a . " is " . $sellers[$a - 1] . ' with ' . $points[$a] . '<br>';
        $a++;
    }
}
```

I am trying to output this:

```
The seller top 1 is Edvin with 10<br>
The seller top 2 is Julio with 9<br>
The seller top 3 is Rene with 8<br>
```

Comment: Where is `$sellers` array?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The echo is not displaying the total points.

Comment: You can't access those associative keys with numbers (`$a`).  Do you only want to show the first three elements/sellers?

Comment: I don't get the concept of while loop there. Seller name is the array key and the array field value is what you are looking for.

Comment: @mickmackusa what is the correct way to access the associative values in this type of loop?

Comment: Please explain what you actually intend to do.  This is incredibly basic, so I am hesitant to post an answer.  Remove `[$a - 1]` and `[$a]`.  `$seller` and `$points` are strings and they are ready for printing as is.

Comment: Yes, my purpose is to access the first three sellers with their respective points.

Comment: So you want leave - `break` out of - your foreach loop after it has iterated for three times. Adding another loop inside the first one is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to access the first three elements, so slice the array before looping, you can increment the counter as you iterate.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/061e134ec72066c70627f6d5408464b60e10abd0))

```
$sellers = array('Edvin' => 10, 'Julio' => 9, 'Rene' => 8, 'Jorge' =>7, 'Marvin' => 6,
                    'Brayan' => 5, 'Sergio' => 4, 'Delfido' => 3, 'Jhon' => 2);

$i = 0;
foreach (array_slice($sellers, 0, 3) as $seller => $points) {
    echo "The seller top " . ++$i . " is $seller with $points<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
The seller top 1 is Edvin with 10<br>
The seller top 2 is Julio with 9<br>
The seller top 3 is Rene with 8<br>
```

---

If you want to control the loop with the counter and omit the `array_slice()` call, you will need to write a loop break.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($sellers as $seller => $points) {
    echo "The seller top " . ++$i . " is $seller with $points<br>";
    if ($i == 3) break;
}
```

Comment: But what if the last record has the highest sales? If i am not mistaken you get the first 3 always right?

Comment: The sample input is clearly already sorted.  If you are asking me if I know how to sort a 1-dim array DESC, the answer is "yes".  http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a While Loop inside a foreach Loop ?

You can do this:

```
$sellers = array(
  'Edvin'   => 10,
  'Julio'   =>  9,
  'Rene'    =>  8,
  'Jorge'   =>  7,
  'Marvin'  =>  6,
  'Brayan'  =>  5,
  'Sergio'  =>  4,
  'Delfido' =>  3,
  'Jhon'    =>  2
);

$a = 1;
foreach (array_flip($sellers) as $points => $seller) {
  if ($a < 4) {
    echo "The seller top " . $a . " is " . $seller . ' with ' . $points . '<br>';
    $a++;
   }
 }
```

If you want to use a while loop you can do this to:

```
$sellers = array(
  'Edvin'   => 10,
  'Julio'   =>  9,
  'Rene'    =>  8,
  'Jorge'   =>  7,
  'Marvin'  =>  6,
  'Brayan'  =>  5,
  'Sergio'  =>  4,
  'Delfido' =>  3,
  'Jhon'    =>  2
);

$a = 0;
// Get Associative Keys
$keys = array_keys($sellers);
while($a < 3){
    // Get Assoc INDEX at position
    $index = $keys[$a];

    echo "The seller top " . ($a+1) . " is " . $index . ' with ' . $sellers[$index] . '<br>';
    $a++;
}
```

Comment: My feedback: 1. There is no point to calling `array_flip()` 2. Continuing to iterate and perform no action is poor practice. 3. `$index` is not a logical variable name considering that the value is an associative key. (`$name` or `$key` would be better)